# Wordpress Cron Job to download files

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am using pitch print to get customers to edit business cards through a woocommerce set up. When the order is created a link gets appended to the order for the admin/shop manager to download the rendered pdf.

The pdf is stored on the pitch print server, I believe via s3, and you need a signature/key to access the file. Which is ordinarily installed on the plugin admin.

I would like to set up a cron to automatically download the file, either when the order is created, or happy to settle for a times interval.

Post a comment for more clarification if needed.

Cheers

Andrew

Comment: Download the file from another server to yours I guess

Comment: Yes that is the idea, but I have no idea how to do it...

Comment: Check what are the urls one would use when downloading them normally from within the browser, understand the parameters and use it with file_get_contents() or curl